# n-way file merge in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have several files from Java application (Gigaspaces logs) from multiple hosts which I need to merge based on date/time value.

Since every log file is already sorted, I need to get a first record from every file into an array, decide which one have a key with minimum value, merge it to result file, get a new line from the same file & repeat.

Record's definition - first line have a key and all following lines have no key, example:

```
2015-04-05 02:33:42,135 GSC SEVERE [com.gigaspaces.lrmi] - LRMI Transport Protocol caught server exception caused by [/10.0.1.2:46949] client.; Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:311)
    at com.gigaspaces.lrmi.SmartByteBufferCache.get(SmartByteBufferCache.java:50)
    at com.gigaspaces.lrmi.nio.Reader.readBytesFromChannelNoneBlocking(Reader.java:410)
    at com.gigaspaces.lrmi.nio.Reader.readBytesNonBlocking(Reader.java:644)
    at com.gigaspaces.lrmi.nio.Reader.bytesToStream(Reader.java:509)
    at com.gigaspaces.lrmi.nio.Reader.readRequest(Reader.java:112)
    at com.gigaspaces.lrmi.nio.ChannelEntry.readRequest(ChannelEntry.java:121)
    at com.gigaspaces.lrmi.nio.Pivot.handleReadRequest(Pivot.java:445)
    at com.gigaspaces.lrmi.nio.selector.handler.ReadSelectorThread.handleRead(ReadSelectorThread.java:81)
    at com.gigaspaces.lrmi.nio.selector.handler.ReadSelectorThread.handleConnection(ReadSelectorThread.java:45)
    at com.gigaspaces.lrmi.nio.selector.handler.AbstractSelectorThread.doSelect(AbstractSelectorThread.java:74)
    at com.gigaspaces.lrmi.nio.selector.handler.AbstractSelectorThread.run(AbstractSelectorThread.java:50)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Ideally, result file should contain key, directory/filename.log & rest of the record.

Questions:

1. How to get a record from file in Ruby?
2. How to open multiple files and iterate through them using algorithm described above?

Comment: So, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "get a new line from the same file & repeat.", as only the first line of each file contains the date/time key.

Comment: Nope, every file is a log file and every line in every file might start with a key or with something else. Most of the entries are single-lined, but there might be multi-line entries like Java traces

Comment: I edited my answer in light of your comment. My confusion stemmed from your third (one-sentence) paragraph. I suggest you edit your question to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

Read all lines from all files that begin with a date-time string into an array, then sort the array by the date-time strings:

```
require 'date'

def get_key_rows(*fnames)
  fnames.flat_map do |fname|
    IO.foreach(fname).with_object([]) do |s, arr|
      dt = DateTime.strptime(s[0, 19], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') rescue nil
      arr << [s[0, 19], fname, s[19..-1].rstrip] if dt 
    end
  end.sort_by(&:first)
end
```

This method returns an array of three-element arrays. Each three-element array corresponds to a key line in one of the files, comprised of the date/time string, the filename and the remainder of the part of the line that follows the date/time string. Note that it is not necessary for key lines to be ordered within each file. The method uses:

- [DateTime#strptime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime) to identify key rows;
- [Enumerable#flat_map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map), rather than [Enumerable#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) followed by [Array#flatten](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten); and
- [Enumerable#sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) to sort the key rows by date/time.

Regarding `sort_by`, note that the strings can be sorted by the date/time strings, rather than by corresponding `DateTime` objects, because the form of the date/time string is `'yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss'`.

**Examples**

Let's create some files:

```
IO.write("f0", "2015-04-05 02:33:42,135 more stuff in f0\n" +
               "more in f0\n" +
               "2015-04-05 04:33:42,135 more stuff in f0\n" +
               "even more in f0")
  #=> 108

IO.write("f1", "2015-04-04 02:33:42,135 more stuff in f1\n" +
               "2015-04-06 02:33:42,135 more stuff in f1\n" + 
               "more in f1")
  #=> 92


IO.write("f2", "something in f2\n" +
               "2015-04-05 02:33:43,135 more stuff in f2\n" +
               "even more in f2\n" +
               "2015-04-04 02:23:42,135 more stuff in f2")
  #=> 113

get_key_rows('f0', 'f1', 'f2')
  #=> [["2015-04-04 02:23:42", "f2", ",135 more stuff in f2"],
  #    ["2015-04-04 02:33:42", "f1", ",135 more stuff in f1"],
  #    ["2015-04-05 02:33:42", "f0", ",135 more stuff in f0"],
  #    ["2015-04-05 02:33:43", "f2", ",135 more stuff in f2"],
  #    ["2015-04-05 04:33:42", "f0", ",135 more stuff in f0"],
  #    ["2015-04-06 02:33:42", "f1", ",135 more stuff in f1"]]
```